# Lazy loading dojo modules: does dojo check its cache?

Tags: caching, dojo, lazy-loading

When evaluating `dojo.require` statements, dojo tracks which modules and resources have been required and doesn't download them many times, but takes them from cache.

But what if I require a module lazily, for example, when a button is clicked, - does dojo check its cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the same mechanism is used to make sure a module is not loaded, during page load and after page load, when responding to dynamic events, as long as it is a normal dojo.require("my.module.name") call.